# Sorting a numpy array

Tags: arrays, sorting, numpy, row, multiple-columns

I have a numpy array and I wanted to sort the rows.

```
    >>f1
    array([['b', '3'],
           ['v', '7'],
           ['a', '1'],
           ['a', '0'],
           ['a', '5'],
           ['f', '7'],
           ['f', '5'],
           ['a', '2'], dtype=object)
```

I am using sort() and I am getting like this

```
    >> f1.sort()
    >> print f1
    [['3' 'b']
     ['7' 'v']
     ['1' 'a']
     ['0' 'a']
     ['5' 'a']
     ['7' 'f']
     ['5' 'f']
     ['2' 'a']]
```

But what I need is,

```
    [['a' '0']
     ['a' '1']
     ['a' '2']
     ['a' '5']
     ['b' '3']
     ['f' '5']
     ['f' '7']
     ['v' '7']]
```

Can someone help me

Comment: How do we have `['a' '7']` in the o/p?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy sort accepts an axis to sort over:

```
from numpy import array

f= array([['b', '3'],
           ['v', '7'],
           ['a', '1'],
           ['a', '0'],
           ['a', '5'],
           ['f', '7'],
           ['f', '5'],
           ['a', '2']])

f.sort(0)
print f
```

I get:

```
[['a' '0']
 ['a' '1']
 ['a' '2']
 ['a' '3']
 ['b' '5']
 ['f' '5']
 ['f' '7']
 ['v' '7']]
```

**EDIT:**

I just realized this may not be what you wanted. `numpy` sort sorts along the axis over all possible traversals (e.g. in this case sorts each column separately). To do a 'row' sort by first index:

```
print array(sorted(f,key=lambda x: list(x)))
```

**NM**, apparently got it right  the first time :)